Two-level system in a thermal bath
I have a 2-level system, with the resonant frequency $\omega_0$ in a thermal bath, by which I mean that I have photons with mean frequency and standard deviation of frequency at a temperature $T$ given by:
$$\langle\omega\rangle = \sigma_\omega = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{k_B T}{\hbar}$$
I can assume that $|\omega_0 - \langle\omega\rangle| \ll \omega_0$. If I start in the ground state and I assume I am in the perturbative regime (i.e. only a very small population gets transferred to the excited state), how can I calculate the population transfer to the excited state as a function of time?

As you ask about the population density as a function of time: Are you interested in the dynamics of reaching the equilibrium? To solve this you need more details in your model (namely, the interaction between the system and the bath).

In this case I want to know the population as a function of time when the population in the excited state is still very small, so I would say this is still very far from reaching equilibrium (i.e. we can ignore stimulated and spontaneous emission effects). As for the interaction it's an electric dipole interaction, for a transition dipole moment, d.
